# How to set toolbar title appear on scroll from bottom as it implemented in Apple Music Android app?

Tags: android, animation, scroll, toolbar, apple-music

I want to implement scroll behavior for Toolbar title as its implemented in Apple Music Android app.

Detailed screenshots of its behaviour: 
[Initial State](https://sun9-43.userapi.com/c854216/v854216871/b7b64/cUFk4ODmerM.jpg),
[Start scrolling](https://sun9-28.userapi.com/c852228/v852228871/1902cc/eTArYQlNZsE.jpg),
[Continue Scrolling](https://sun9-7.userapi.com/c850724/v850724871/187c41/P8mL3U5ONzs.jpg),
[End of scroll](https://sun9-47.userapi.com/c850216/v850216871/1b1d60/h36BV1FNBkk.jpg)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/brucetoo/Android-ObservableScrollView)

Comment: @Piyush as I understand, I can use this observable to implement this animation by myself? The problem is, I'm pretty new for this and don't know with what to start. Can you help me with "steps through" or something to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Piyush said, https://github.com/brucetoo/Android-ObservableScrollView is exactly the library you need for this. This is how you'd go about it

1. Import the library by going to your app's Gradle file and pasting this

   ```
   implementation 'com.github.ksoichiro:android-observablescrollview:1.5.0'
   ```
2. Make your xml layout and instead of using a standard `ScrollView` to wrap it, use an `ObservableScrollView`. Outside of the scroll view, make a toolbar that will host your menu buttons as well as the title i.e. "Library"
3. In you Java/ Kotlin file, attach a listener to the scroll view by using `listView.setScrollViewCallbacks`. Provide an object implementing the `ObservableScrollViewCallbacks` interface as an argument.
4. In the callback, change the YTranslation and alpha values of the title in your toolbar based on the scroll factor

I don't have android studio in front of me, so I can't provide any code, but this is the jist of it.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to do it with your instructions!